# Powershell - Selecting just the results of an IF statement

Tags: powershell, office365

I am looking to compare the member list of groups in JSON files against the actual group in Office 365 and export a list with only the name of the group and the members from the JSON file that are not members in the production group.

I start with importing the JSON data:

```
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -path "c:\tmp\json" -filter *.json | get-content -raw

$allobjects = $jsonFiles | convertfrom-json
```

Next, I have a variable that gets the members of all Office 365 unified groups:

```
$prodGrpMemb = Get-UnifiedGroup | Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -LinkType members | select -ExpandProperty name
```

I now need to create a function that will provide the desired output.  So far, this is what I have:

```
function get-MissingMembers {

 [CmdletBinding()]
 Param(
 [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
 $InputObject,

 [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
 $prodMember
 )

    Process {
                foreach($displayname in $InputObject.displayname){
                    if($InputObject.members -notin $prodMember)
                    {
                        write-output $InputObject.displayname,$InputObject.members | `
                        out-file -Append c:\tmp\MissingMembers.txt
                        }
                         else{
                                continue
                              }
                }
        }
}
```

I then call the function with this:

```
$allobjects | get-GroupCount -prodMember $prodGrpMemb
```

The problem is that current write-output selects all groups.  How do I select only the results that match the IF statement?

Thank you in advance for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what you've coded for.
Yet, you have logic and syntax issues in your code.

Is this really a collection?

```
$InputObject
$prodMember
```

As they’re currently written, both parameters will accept only a single value. Declaring them as [string[]] would let them accept an entire collection of values. You’d then enumerate this using a Foreach loop, so you could work with one value at a time.

```
[string[]]$InputObject
[string[]$prodMember
```

Also, If so, you don't show where you get these or what they look like.

With this...

```
$InputObject.displayname
```

… You are only returning the displayname from all possible items in the $InputObject array/collection. So, this …

```
$InputObject.members
```

... is not prudent to what you are after. You just called the default collection. Hence getting them all.

As for this.

```
write-output $displayname,$InputObject.members | 
out-file -Append c:\tmp\MissingMembers.txt
```

As written, this will display the current displaname being processed and all the members from the $InputObject array. This is why you are seeing them all.

If you are after only the MissingMembers, then you don't need the $InputObject.members

So, something like this... should work, but not tested on my side since I have no idea what's really in those to collections.

```
function get-MissingMembers 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$prodMember
    )

    Process 
    {
        # Return the displayname from the InputObject
        foreach($displayname in $InputObject.Displayname)
        {
            # Validate displaynmae is a prodMember
            if($displayname -notin $prodMember)
            {
                # Generate report of only non-matching member names
                write-output $displayname | 
                out-file -Append 'c:\tmp\MissingMembers.txt'
            }
            else
            { continue }
        }
    }
}
```